# Replacing Divi Fullwidth Menu with UberMenu

Tags: php, html, wordpress, menu

I am using Divi Theme and I need a way to integrate UberMenu in the Fullwidth Menu module.

I searched `header.php` but I can't see any code regarding the Fullwidth Menu module.

This is what I find when I look at it with the inspector

```
<div class="et_pb_fullwidth_menu
            et_pb_module
            et_pb_bg_layout_light
            et_pb_text_align_left
            et_dropdown_animation_fade
            et_pb_fullwidth_menu_0"
     style="background-color: #ffffff;"
     data-bg_color="#ffffff"
```

I can't find something like this on the theme.

I tried to use the same theme location but it looks like the ubermenu takes no effect , I can  still see the normal Fullwidth Menu.

```html
<div class="entry-content">
     <div style="" id="wp-wpined_textarea-wrap" class="wp-core-ui wp-editor-wrap html-active"><link rel="stylesheet" id="dashicons-css" href="ht.tp://localhost/wordpress/wp-includes/css/dashicons.min.css?ver=4.3.1" type="text/css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" id="editor-buttons-css" href="ht.tp://localhost/wordpress/wp-includes/css/editor.min.css?ver=4.3.1" type="text/css" media="all">
<div style="width: 307px;" id="wp-wpined_textarea-editor-tools" class="wp-editor-tools hide-if-no-js"><div id="wp-wpined_textarea-media-buttons" class="wp-media-buttons"><button type="button" id="insert-media-button" class="button insert-media add_media" data-editor="wpined_textarea"><span class="wp-media-buttons-icon"></span> Add Media</button></div>
<div class="wp-editor-tabs"><button type="button" id="wpined_textarea-tmce" class="wp-switch-editor switch-tmce" data-wp-editor-id="wpined_textarea">Visual</button>
<button type="button" id="wpined_textarea-html" class="wp-switch-editor switch-html" data-wp-editor-id="wpined_textarea">Text</button>
</div>
</div>
<div id="wp-wpined_textarea-editor-container" class="wp-editor-container"><div style="padding: 0px; height: 0px;" id="qt_wpined_textarea_toolbar" class="quicktags-toolbar"><div style="width: 307px;" id="qt_wpined_textarea_toolbar_inner"><input id="qt_wpined_textarea_strong" class="ed_button button button-small" aria-label="Bold" value="b" type="button"><input id="qt_wpined_textarea_em" class="ed_button button button-small" aria-label="Italic" value="i" type="button"><input id="qt_wpined_textarea_link" class="ed_button button button-small" aria-label="Insert link" value="link" type="button"><input id="qt_wpined_textarea_block" class="ed_button button button-small" aria-label="Blockquote" value="b-quote" type="button"><input id="qt_wpined_textarea_del" class="ed_button button button-small" aria-label="Deleted text (strikethrough)" value="del" type="button"><input id="qt_wpined_textarea_ins" class="ed_button button button-small" aria-label="Inserted text" value="ins" type="button"><input id="qt_wpined_textarea_img" class="ed_button button button-small" aria-label="Insert image" value="img" type="button"><input id="qt_wpined_textarea_ul" class="ed_button button button-small" aria-label="Bulleted list" value="ul" type="button"><input id="qt_wpined_textarea_ol" class="ed_button button button-small" aria-label="Numbered list" value="ol" type="button"><input id="qt_wpined_textarea_li" class="ed_button button button-small" aria-label="List item" value="li" type="button"><input id="qt_wpined_textarea_code" class="ed_button button button-small" aria-label="Code" value="code" type="button"><input id="qt_wpined_textarea_more" class="ed_button button button-small" aria-label="Insert Read More tag" value="more" type="button"><input id="qt_wpined_textarea_close" class="ed_button button button-small" title="Close all open tags" value="close tags" type="button"></div></div><textarea class="wp-editor-area" rows="20" autocomplete="off" cols="40" name="wpined_textarea" id="wpined_textarea"></textarea></div>
</div>

<span class="wpined-con" rel="3223"><div class="et_pb_section et_pb_fullwidth_section  et_pb_section_0 et_section_regular"><div class="et_pb_fullwidth_menu et_pb_module et_pb_bg_layout_light et_pb_text_align_left et_dropdown_animation_fade  et_pb_fullwidth_menu_0" style="background-color: #ffffff;" data-bg_color="#ffffff">
    <div class="et_pb_row clearfix">
     <nav class="fullwidth-menu-nav"><ul style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);" id="menu-salon" class="fullwidth-menu nav downwards"><li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-3251"><a href="ht.tp://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=3243">Services</a></li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-3252"><a href="ht.tp://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=3241">Gallery</a></li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-3250"><a href="ht.tp://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=3245">About us</a></li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-3249"><a href="ht.tp://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=3247">Contact</a></li>
</ul></nav>
     <div class="et_mobile_nav_menu">
      <a href="#" class="mobile_nav closed">
       <span class="mobile_menu_bar"></span>
      <ul style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);" id="mobile_menu1" class="et_mobile_menu"><li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-3251 et_first_mobile_item"><a href="ht.tp://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=3243">Services</a></li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-3252"><a href="ht.tp://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=3241">Gallery</a></li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-3250"><a href="ht.tp://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=3245">About us</a></li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-3249"><a href="ht.tp://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=3247">Contact</a></li>
</ul></a>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Can you paste more code around your div, seen from the inspector?

Comment: I just added more code.

Comment: Can you search for the text of wpined-con in your project?

Comment: It's a function that I can find only in Core.jss(inline) and JSQuery

Comment: Can you paste that function into your question?

Comment: In CSS we have the contents of Core.jss and in JS we have the JSQuery.  https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QjBQNR

Comment: I believe you should debug the js and see when its content is added. In a few hours you should have the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Check this: http://sevenspark.com/docs/ubermenu-3/theme-integration/divi
This should works for you.